# R - SpatialPointsDataFrame from a list of SpatialPoints

Tags: r, spatial, lapply

How to create a SpatialPointsDataFrame from a list of SpatialPoints?

In the following there´s a code of a list containing SpatialPoints:.

```
SP1 <- SpatialPoints(cbind(1,5))
SP2 <- SpatialPoints(cbind(2,4))
SP3 <- SpatialPoints(cbind(3,3))

SP.l<-list(SP1,SP2, SP3)
```

What I´m looking for is a way to extract the SpatialPoints from the list and create a SpatialPointsDataFrame out of it.

With the following code I can get single SpatialPoints out of the list:

```
coords_3 = SP.l[[3]]@coords
data_3 = as.data.frame(SP.l[[3]])

SPDF_3 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=coords_3, data=as.data.frame(data_3))
```

However I´d like receive all at once. 
Maybe something like:

```
SP <- SpatialPoints(lapply(1:length(lidR.clip.SP.l), function(i) {
```

...

**EDIT:**
what was missing was:

```
SP.l <- do.call("rbind", SP.l)
```

That´s what I was actually looking for.

thx!

Comment: This is not a MWE and pictures are not code nor data unless the q is abt image processing. Please provide a minimal, representative data set to go along with the code you've provided.

Comment: ok. i´ll prepare a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no minimal working example as hrbrmstr. You need to provide one. For now, I use a sample data from the GISTools package and demonstrate one way. There is a data set call newhaven in the package. `breach` is the data. I made a copy of it and created `foo`, which class is `SpatialPoints`. I created two list elements using `foo`.

Using your code, I looped through each list element and converted SpatialPoints to SpatialPointsDataFrame. I hope you can figure out how to apply the following code to your case.

```
library(GISTools)

data(newhaven)  
foo <- breach

mylist <- list(foo1 = breach[1:10, ],
               foo2 = breach[11:20, ])

lapply(1:length(mylist), function(x){
    SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = mylist[[x]]@coords,
                           data = as.data.frame(mylist[[x]]))
})
```

If you want to bind all SPDFs, then you can try the following.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(mylist), function(x){
                   SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = mylist[[x]]@coords,
                                          data = as.data.frame(mylist[[x]]))
          })
)
```

Comment: you´re right. I jsut added a minimal working example. Your code works fine for turning a list of SpatialPoints into a list of SpatialPointsDataFrames. However what I´d like to receive is a SpatialPointsDataFrame containing all SpatialPoints which are now stored in a list.

Comment: @N'ya I just saw your example. If you replace `mylist` with `SP.l`, I think the code above will work, I think.

Comment: yes, it works, however it creates a list of SPDF instead of a single SPDF. I managed it by using do.call. thx!

Answer (score 0):

what was missing was:

```
SP.l <- do.call("rbind", SP.l)
```

That´s what I was actually looking for.

thx!